# Display frame for certain amount of Time

Tags: java, splash-screen

I Have 3 classes, the main.class, login.class and then a splash-screen.class

my splash-screen doesn't have a main in it, it only runs when the main.class runs, problem is I want my splash screen to appear only for 3 seconds, then it must disappear and show the login .class (which just has controls to log in)

How do I do that?

At the moment when I run the main, both the splashscreen.class and login.class apear

Answer (score 1):

Use a Swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html):

- display the splash frame
- create a Timer with a 3 seconds delay, and call `setRepeats(false)` on this timer. Its ActionListener should hide the splash frame, and show the Login frame
- start the timer

Comment: My brain thought `false`, and my fingers typed `true` :-). Thanks for noticing my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Code shown below might work for you:

```
 public static void showSplash(int duration) {
                SplashScreen splash1 = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
                if(splash1==null){
                File file1=new File("splash.jpg");
                String imgfile1=file1.getAbsolutePath();

                JWindow splash = new JWindow();
                JPanel content = (JPanel)splash.getContentPane();

                int width = 655;
                int height = 442;
                Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                int x = (screen.width-width)/2;
                int y = (screen.height-height)/2;
                splash.setBounds(x,y,width,height);

                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imgfile1));
                content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                splash.setVisible(true);
            // Wait a little while, maybe while loading resources
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(duration);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                splash.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
```

You can call this method at the first line of your `main()` method.

Comment: -1: either this is called in the EDT, and it will freeze the GUI because of the sleep call (never sleep in the EDT!), or it's called from another thread, and it doesn't respect the Swing threading rule, which mandate that every access to a Swing component is done from the EDT.